# Why can I not obtain some cookies

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to create a bot to read cookies but I'm failing to do so, what the hell am I doing wrong?

````
import urllib
import http.cookiejar

URL = 'https://roblox.com'


def extract_cookies():
    
    cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

    url_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
    
    url_opener.open(URL)
    print(URL)
    for cookie in cookie_jar:
        print("[Cookie Name = %s] [Cookie Value = %s]" %(cookie.name, cookie.value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    extract_cookies()```
````

Comment: HTTP Error 308: Permanent Redirect

Comment: a different URL works

Comment: Trying to get the .ROBLOSECURITY cookie (HTTPOnly)

Answer (score 0):

It's a permanent redirect: `https://roblox.com` redirects to `https://www.roblox.com`. This is why you get an HTTP 308 status code. Note the difference in `www`.

The server tells you where to go in the HTTP response:

```
HTTP GET    https://roblox.com/
--
HTTP/2 308 Permanent Redirect
location: https://www.roblox.com/
```

So update your URL to `https://www.roblox.com`

Comment: It works but Its not extracting the correct cookies

Comment: The cookies from ```https:// www.roblox. com```and ```https ://roblox. com are not the same

Comment: @Ardan cookies are mostly used by the server to identify a client. `roblox.com` and `www.roblox.com` are likely to be different servers. In fact, it's likely you will get different cookies if you hit a different server handling your request (there are many serving roblox). Please specify what you expect to see, and where the error is. It's hard to help without understanding what you trying to do and where the error is.

Comment: I'm expecting to see the .ROBLOSECURITY cookie which can be found at roblox.com. it is the cookie that has access to my account which www.roblox. com doesnt store the cookie @oleksii

Comment: Oh, I see - your code first needs to log in to roblox, so that the server will return you that cookie. Otherwise, you are not authenticated, and the server will not set that cookie. You may want to have a look at roblox API to see if you can achieve the same with the APIs: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference